# Torah is the Name of the Holy One

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, zohar

From where (which verses, or arguments) do the commentators derive that Torah is the Name of the Holy One (as seems to be refered to by many commentators and in the Zohar).

Comment: Could you share 2-3 references that show Torah is a name of God? (you probably mean **a** name rather than **the** name)

Comment: Ramban (in his introduction to the Torah) says something like כל התורה שמותיו של הקב"ה (all the Torah is God's name). Are you thinking of that? If so, I don't think it literally means the word "Torah"

Comment: @mbloch Zohar 2:60b, 2:90b

Comment: @ba if that's the way to read it what does it mean?

Comment: @mbloch a little bit differently also in Zohar 1:24a and 2:60a "the Torah and the Holy One, blessed be He, are one."

Comment: @Levi thanks, ideally you would [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/88944/edit) those in the question to make it stronger

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, it's based on the Zohar [II:87b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.87b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [III:98b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.98b.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> תָּנֵינָן, **אוֹרַיְיתָא כֹּלָּא שְׁמָא קַדִּישָׁא הִיא**, דְּלֵית לָךְ מִלָּה בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא דְּלָא כָּלִיל בִּשְׁמָא קַדִּישָׁא
>
> אֶלָּא אוֹרַיְיתָא כּוּלָהּ סָתִים וְגַלְיָא, כְּמָה דִּשְׁמָא קַדִּישָׁא סָתִים וְגַלְיָא, בְּגִין **דְּאוֹרַיְיתָא כּוּלָהּ שְׁמָא קַדִּישָׁא הִיא**, וְעַל דָּא אִיהִי סָתִים וְגַלְיָא

Roughly in the same period of the emergence of Zohar, Ramban cites again Kabbalistic tradition in his [introduction to Bereishit](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94):

> עוד יש בידינו קבלה של אמת, **כי כל התורה כולה שמותיו של הקב"ה**, שהתיבות מתחלקות לשמות בענין אחד. כאילו תחשוב על דרך משל, כי פסוק בראשית יתחלק לתיבות אחרות, כגון: 'בראש יתברא אלהים', וכל התורה כן, מלבד צירופיהן וגימטריאותיהם של שמות. וכבר כתב רבינו שלמה בפירושיו בתלמוד: "ענין השם הגדול של ע"ב, באיזה ענין הוא, בשלשה פסוקים: 'ויסע', 'ויבא',, 'ויט'. ומפני זה ספר תורה שטעה בו באות אחת במלא או בחסר - פסול. כי זה הענין יחייב אותנו לפסול ספר תורה שיחסר בו ו' אחד ממלות 'אותם' שבאו מהם ל"ט מלאים בתורה, או שיכתוב הו' באחד משאר החסרים, וכן כיוצא בזה, אף על פי שאינו מעלה ולא מוריד כפי העולה במחשבה

<sub>Disclaimer: I am an honest mitnaged.</sub>

Comment: This teaching of Ramban also follows the teaching from Sefer HaTashbetz, part II, Teshuva 209 and Sefer Avodat HaKodesh 3:11:6.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I thought "עוד יש בידינו קבלה של אמת" made it clear that he accepted this teaching

Comment: Why was the disclaimer necessary?

Comment: @ezra Because I don't have any familiarity with Zohar, and there may be other MY members with better insight, who can improve upon my answer or correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Ah! I see. I +1 this answer though; I thought it was good. By the way the Vilna Gaon was a big scholar on the Zohar.

Comment: @ezra I don't have anything against chasidim (so I may not be a proper mitnaged either). I've heard this statement often, and wanted to get the source of it. If I finish Bavli and Yerushalmi ב"ה and I'm still alive, I'll try to look at Zohar as well! :-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi Hatzlachah Rabbah in your journey! If only more people would see the value in studying the Bavli and Yerushalmi instead of always trying to dabble in kabbalah which they cannot fully understand...

Comment: Don't forget to follow the procedure of Rabbi Zeira outlined in Bava Metzia 85a. When you have completed all of Bavli, fast for 100 consecutive days in order to forget all you learned in Bavli before beginning your study of Yerushalmi. Otherwise, all your preconceptions from Bavli will hinder your ability to learn Yerushalmi correctly.

Comment: From https://thenutgarden.wordpress.com/2017/06/13/from-the-mouth-of-a-sage-by-rabbi-yehudah-ashlag-baal-ha-sullam/

Comment: Torah is the name of the blessed Holy One” [see Rabbi Ezra of Gerona, Peirush le-Shir ha-Shirim, 548; Naḥmanides, introduction to Commentary on the Torah, 6-7; Zohar 2:60a, 87a, 90b, 124a; 3:13b, 19a, 21a, 35b-36a, 73a, 89b, 98b, 159a, 265b, 298b; Rabbi Moshe de León, Sefer ha-Rimmon, 341-42; Berit Menuḥa: Introduction; OY; Galante]

Comment: @Kazibácsi could you give a translation for your answer?

Comment: My Aramaic is really poor, for a precise translation maybe we should ask @ezra, or somone else...